# Перенос rich текста между редакторами

Tags: c++, редактор-текста

Подскажите, как переносится форматирование и rich текст при копировании между совершенно разными редакторами, например Google Docs в браузере и Word на ПК. Что за технология?
Более конкретно: есть html в буфере обмена, надо его преобразовать так, чтобы при вставке в редактор был уже текст.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В буфере обмена данные могут храниться в нескольких представлениях (mime-type) одновременно. 
Приложение-источник (copy) помещает в буфер отдельную копию данных для каждого из поддерживаемых представлений, а потребитель (paste) выбирает наиболее удобный для себя формат, из тех которые понимает. В некоторых приложениях доступен выбор представления, которое будет использовано (см. Paste Special в ворде).
Пример на Qt:

```
QByteArray svg=BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(
            <svg height="100" width="100">
              <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
              <text style="font-size:50px" x="20" y="75">Foo</text>
            </svg>
           );
QImage image;
image.loadFromData( svg );

auto*mime=new QMimeData();
mime->setText("Foo"); // Как текст (будет понимать notepad).
mime->setData( "text/html" ,  "<i>F</i><b>o</b><u>o</u>" ); // Поймет ворд
mime->setData( "image/svg+xml" ,svg );
mime->setImageData( image ); // заполняет сразу несколько графических форматов
auto*clip=QApplication::clipboard();
clip->clear();
clip->setMimeData(mime);
```

Comment: Уже независимо нашёл ответ, но не было времени отписать.
Вы совершенно верно ответили, спасибо :)
Единственное, в Qt можно сразу setHtml, не обязательно вручную типы ставить.